# Combinations to find highest result in pandas/ python

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a dataframe that resembles this:

```
  Disease  Gene1  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4
      D1    0.10    0.12   0.26    0.1
      D2    1.00    1.00   0.01    0.13
      D3    0.1     0.18   0.50    0.17
      D4    0.25    0.10   0.31    0.41
      D5    0.01    0.01   0.21    0.44
      D6    0.31    0.33   0.81    0.12
      D7    0.61    0.03   0.41    0.36
      D8    0.05    0.84   0.38    0.83
```

but it is about 500 columns wide and thousands of rows deep.

For each disease I would like to consider **all combination of Gene columns** whose sum yields a higher value for that disease than any other disease.

From this set of combinations I want to select those with the **shortest length**.

And from among those of shortest length, I wish to select the combination which
produces the **maximimum sum** for that disease.

For example, for D2, Gene1 + Gene2 has the highest sum.

As you would guess in this case the order doesn't matter. I hope this makes
sense. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

I think the problem is i have not piped the data into powerset properly. The code is just running without giving a result or timing out.

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
start = time.time()

def PP():
    PP = pd.read_csv('datainfile.csv')
    return PP

PP = PP()



#np.random.seed(2015)

def powerset(iterable, reverse=False, rvals=None):
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"""
    s = list(iterable)
    N = len(s)
    if rvals is None:
        rvals = range(N, -1, -1) if reverse else range(N + 1)
    return IT.chain.from_iterable(
        IT.combinations(s, r) for r in rvals)

# df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
#ncols, nrows, ndiseases = 515, 5000, 200
Genes_list = list(PP.iloc[[0],1:].columns)
concatHS_list = list(PP.iloc[0:,0])

PP = PP.set_index(['concatHS'])


result = dict()
for combo in powerset(PP.columns):
    if len(combo) < 2: continue
    concatHS = PP[list(combo)].sum(axis=1).argmax()
    if concatHS not in result:
        result[concatHS] = combo
    if not set(PP.index).difference(result.keys()):
        break

for concatHS, combo in result.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(concatHS, combo))

end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start
print("Time elapsed:", elapsed)
```

Comment: Do you need all combinations of all 500 columns? you are looking at a nasty number here...

Comment: Not all...I will use a different numbers of columns but 515 is about the max...hopefully 100-200 will do the trick.

Comment: Also is this something that i can push to the gpu for faster performance.

Comment: How many diseases are there?

Comment: about 600 but some may be related so i can group them down to around 200

Comment: @imaluengo I have used samples which i used to build the table above but i was hoping to find an optimal combination. The data is not consistent

Comment: I'm having trouble with this sentence: "the smallest no of combinations that each one will come out on top."  Do you mean for each D the combination that both maximises D's score and doesn't score another D higher?

Comment: @L.AmberO'Hearn> yes you have guessed what i am trying to do correctly.

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond I think i may have deleted the post by accident. I thought i was deleting my comment. can you repost it? I am sorry...I am only on the stack overflow for a few weeks.

Comment: @khestonWalkins: You didn't do anything wrong. I deleted my answer because in light of your comment to L.AmberO'Hearn, I realized that my solution did not do what you wanted. In your example, `Gene2+Gene3`,  `Gene2+Gene4`, and `Gene3+Gene4` all score `D8` the highest. My code could pick any one of them -- on the theory that you were looking only for the smallest number of combinations. Now it seems you want `Gene2+Gene4` since that one also maximizes the D score. A brute force solution may still be possible, but run time may be more like 10-15 minutes rather than 5 seconds.

Comment: I see. I still believe it was a great start though. I amgetting some problems initially with the code. I will post it up and show you and let you know where i got stuck.

Comment: I have added an edit to show what i ran. @HappyLeapSecond

Comment: How big is PP? What is PP.shape?

Comment: Suppose the values in `D1` rows are always less than the values in `D2` rows. Then no combination of genes would maximize `D1` over the other diseases. In that case, the powerset loop would never short-circuit, meaning it would require `2**(num genes)` iterations to complete. If `num_genes` is 515, that means 2**515, which means the loop would effectively never end.

Comment: @khestonWalkins: I edited the question to reflect your response to L.AmberO'Hearn's comment. Hopefully this will clarify the problem for others. Please look it over and edit or rollback if necessary.

Comment: print(PP.info())
Index: 186 entries, D1 to D186
Columns: 515 entries, Gene1 to Gene515
dtypes: float64(515)
memory usage: 749.8+ KB
None...I changed the genes names to just Gene1 and Gene515 for simplicity sake same for the disease @HappyLeapSecond